# Flutter Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: flutter

I have an error like this :

```
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                    itemCount: snapshot.data['data'].length,

                                            ^
: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
lib/screens/homepage.dart:33
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                      return Text(snapshot.data['data'][index]['name']);
                                               ^
```

This is my code homepage.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/products';
  //android emulator http://10.0.2.2 mac http://127.0.0.1

  Future getProducts() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Botang Store'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getProducts(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data['data'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data['data'][index]['name']);
                    });
              } else {
                return Text('Data Error');
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

This is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toko_online/screens/homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Botang Store',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: toko_online
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Can anyone solve it? I search for it but I don't find it. I'm new in flutter so I hope everyone can give me the answer for my code. I just follow the tutorial, but when I try it I have an error like this.

Thanks before.

Comment: Your code snippet has several problems.  For starters, look here: [Using FutureBuilder Widget Examples](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-futurebuilder-widget-examples) and [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-multi-dimensional-list-in-dart-78ff332430a)

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer is complaining because there is it doesn't know what type  `snapshot.data['data']` is you need to assign it to a variable and cast it as a `List` or whatever type it actually is (based on the code it looks like a `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`.

```dart
                                \/ it's complaining about this.
return Text(snapshot.data['data'][index]['name']);
```

Something like:

```dart
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final data = snapshot.data['data'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(data[index]['name']);
                    });
              } else {
                return Text('Data Error');
              }
```

You might consider decoding this into meaningful Model classes instead of using raw Maps and Lists.

Comment: It says The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'. How can I define ['data'] as an object? Sorry, I'm really new in flutter, so i don't really understand the basic.

Comment: The analyzer only knows that `snapshot.data` is of type `Object?` because of the way the generic is defined. You need to cast it on order to coerce the analyzer into recognizing it at a `List`

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I found the error. It looks like my version and the tutorial version of SDK in pubspec.yaml is different. ```I used 2.13.0 and in tutorial he used 2.7.0```. Then, it tells me error of ```null safety``` and I turn it off with ```flutter run --no-sound-null-safety```. Thanks Nico for the advice, it looks like I should learn more about flutter.